# WkWebView PDF Export on Mac

Tags: pdf, cocoa, printing, webkit, wkwebview

There are several questions on that subject in SO but most of them are quite old and (I expect) things have changed since.
I simply want to export in PDF format a `WkWebView` . While solutions exist for iOS, I found nothing for Mac.